# "Named" only immediately after a noun, not after a linking verb

Tags: predicative-complement

[Collins cobuild usage](https://books.google.es/books?id=cpBMJW8GE1cC&q=%22Only%20use%20named%20immediately%20after%20a%20noun%22&dq=%22Only%20use%20named%20immediately%20after%20a%20noun%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-ps30vrPyAhXPxYUKHexFCnIQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg) says

> You can use *called* either after a noun or after *be*, *the book was
> called The Goalkeeper's Revenge*.
>
> You only use **named** immediately after a noun, *The victim was an
> 18-year-old girl **named** Marinetta.*

Why is it so?

Comment: The Collins dictionary's online entry for [name](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/name) contains many examples of "named", and almost all of them don't follow that rule. So you should probably just ignore that advice. But I'm curious to see if someone knows what they're really trying to say, and if it can really be useful. Did your COBUILD book mention if this is specific to a certain region, like UK or US?

Comment: As a post-head modifier "named" occurs immediately after a noun. But in a passive construction it can be complement to the verb "be", as in "The baby was named Sarah".

Comment: Ex: Named Sarah, the child demonstrated talent from an early age. The Collins cobuild is only right if it had said, "You **usually** use named..." Of course, there's also **named** used as a verb, like "I named her Sam."

Comment: Named" is also a verb in the passive clause "The baby was named xyz".